# Setup @semantic-release for considering 'refactor' commits in the CHANGELOG

Tags: semantic-versioning, changelog, semantic-release

Using [`@semantic-release`](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/) I'd like to consider **refactor** changes for both, triggering a new release and write down in the CHANGELOG.md file.

So far, I've included **refactor** commits at `"@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"` so they are triggering a patch release:

```json
[
  "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
  {
    "preset": "angular",
    "releaseRules": [
      {
        "type": "refactor",
        "release": "patch"
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

But those commit msgs aren't included in the CHANGELOG file, how can I setup `"@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"` plugin for including refactor commits? I find related [doc](https://github.com/semantic-release/release-notes-generator#configuration) confusing and lack of examples

---

1. generated CHANGELOG example

```
## [0.6.4](.../compare/v0.6.3...v0.6.4) (date)

## [0.6.3](.../compare/v0.6.2...v0.6.3) (date)
```

2. desired CHANGELOG

```
## [0.6.4](.../compare/v0.6.3...v0.6.4) (date)

[[>>INCLUDE HERE COMMIT MSG + LINK<<]]

## [0.6.3](.../compare/v0.6.2...v0.6.3) (date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone finds this useful: we need to config `"@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"` for considering other keywords besides **feat** and **fix** including these dicts:

```json
{
   "type": "refactor",
   "section": "title to be used in changelog.md",
   "hidden": false
}
```

---

For copy-pasting, this setup is gathering both **refactor**, **chore** and **perf** into `## Internal` section (note i needed to write explicitly default values, I guess this is because it's overriding the config)

```json
[
  "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
  {
    "preset": "conventionalCommits",
    "parserOpts": {
      "noteKeywords": [
        "BREAKING CHANGE",
        "BREAKING CHANGES",
        "BREAKING"
      ]
    },
    "presetConfig": {
      "types": [
        {
          "type": "feat",
          "section": "Features"
        },
        {
          "type": "fix",
          "section": "Bug Fixes"
        },
        {
          "type": "chore",
          "section": "Internal",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "type": "refactor",
          "section": "Internal",
          "hidden": false
        },
        {
          "type": "perf",
          "section": "Internal",
          "hidden": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is correct, but I feel its a bit incomplete. Even after adding the above commit types, the release will not be triggered on all the commit types. If you wish to trigger the release on all or selected commit types (ex. `refactor`, `docs` `ci` etc.) you can use the configuration as below:

```js
// release.config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      '@semantic-release/commit-analyzer',
      {
        preset: 'conventionalCommits',
        releaseRules: [
          { type: 'revert', scope: '*', release: 'patch' },
          { type: 'docs', scope: '*', release: 'patch' },
          { type: 'style', scope: '*', release: 'patch' },
          { type: 'chore', scope: '*', release: 'patch' },
          { type: 'refactor', scope: '*', release: 'patch' },
          { type: 'test', scope: '*', release: 'patch' },
          { type: 'build', scope: '*', release: 'patch' },
          { type: 'ci', scope: '*', release: 'patch' },
          { type: 'improvement', scope: '*', release: 'patch' },
        ],
      },
    ],
    [
      '@semantic-release/release-notes-generator',
      {
        preset: 'conventionalCommits',
        presetConfig: {
          types: [
            { type: 'feat', section: 'Features' },
            { type: 'fix', section: 'Bug Fixes' },
            { type: 'perf', section: 'Performance Improvements' },
            { type: 'revert', section: 'Reverts' },
            { type: 'docs', section: 'Documentation', hidden: false },
            { type: 'style', section: 'Styles', hidden: false },
            { type: 'chore', section: 'Miscellaneous Chores', hidden: false },
            { type: 'refactor', section: 'Code Refactors', hidden: false },
            { type: 'test', section: 'Tests', hidden: false },
            { type: 'build', section: 'Build System', hidden: false },
            { type: 'ci', section: 'CI/CD', hidden: false },
            { type: 'improvement', section: 'Improvements', hidden: false },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
    ['@semantic-release/github'],
    [
      '@semantic-release/npm',
      {
        npmPublish: false,
      },
    ],
    '@semantic-release/changelog',
    '@semantic-release/git',
  ],
  branch: 'master',
};
```

###### Working of the above config:

---

`@semantic-release/commit-analyzer` will trigger the release for `feat`, `fix` & `BREAKING CHANGE` as usual. I've only added the rest of the types that are ignored by default. Needless to say that they will be considered as patches and will only bump the `patch` number from [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) in your `tags`, `release notes`, `changelog` & `package.json` file.

`@semantic-release/release-notes-generator` will just make sure that the commits are grouped correctly based on the `type` and will display my custom headings defined with the `section` key.

###### Hope this helps someone in future!